# Zefyr got a large space underneath when embed with image - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am building a Flutter app in which used Zefyr library.

Now I've found an issue in which when I used some images in Zefyr and it gives me more space underneath of the content.

If I don't use any images instead I use only text then it is working fine. I just wonder why when added some images to the Zefyr it gives me that issue?

Here below is the issue that caused space underneath with an image
[image: There is a large space below the image]

Here below when I don't use any images, just only text...
[image: There are no extra spaces below]

Here is the code that I use to display this Zefyr. I use `CustomScrollView` as the parent.

```
SliverFillRemaining(
   hasScrollBody: false,
   child: Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 50),
   child: ZefyrScaffold(
      child: ZefyrTheme(
         data: theme,
         child: ZefyrView(
               document: document,
               imageDelegate: MyAppZefyrImageViewDelegate(),
                ),
        ),
        ),
     ),
 ),
```

Here below is the `MyAppZefyrImageViewDelegate()`

```
class MyAppZefyrImageViewDelegate implements ZefyrImageDelegate<ImageSource> {
  @override
  ImageSource get cameraSource => ImageSource.camera;

  @override
  ImageSource get gallerySource => ImageSource.gallery;

  @override
  Widget buildImage(BuildContext context, String key) {
   if (Uri.parse(key).isAbsolute) {
     return GestureDetector(
     onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => FullPhoto(url: key)));
    },
    child: Image.network(
      key,
      frameBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, int frame,
          bool wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
        if (wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
          return child;
        }
        return AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: frame == null ? 0 : 1,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
final Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(key);
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                FullBase64Photo(base64Str: key)));
  },
  child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
    child: Image.memory(
      bytes,
      filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,
      frameBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, int frame,
          bool wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
        if (wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
          return child;
        }
        return AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: frame == null ? 0 : 1,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}